# Problema con Deployments en Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Tengo un problema con unas apps que corren desde Kubernetes. Estas, estan lanzadas con heml de los repos de Kubeapps. Una vez que se inicia el proceso de lanzado que queda parado porque un Pod requiere una IP externa. He intentado crear un archivo de ingress con Nginx Ingress Controller, pero de ninguna forma llega a correr. 
Gracias!!!

Comment: Cual cloud usas? debe ser que el cluster no reconoce el driver de load balancer para ser implementado. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

En el services del pod puedes agregar la configuracion de la ip externa

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  externalIPs: 
    - A.B.C.D
```

Comment: cuando pongas código, elígelo y dale clic al ícono de `{}` con eso se formatea

Comment: En la pregunta dice claramente IP externa.